# How do I implement Navigation that behaves like a circle?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I have got 4 pages. Now my app starts with page1.

The navigation should work like this:
page1 > page2 > page3 > page4
and than page4 should open page1 again. And so on.

The pages don't need to remember the page that called
`await Navigation.PushModalAsync(NextPage)` 
therefore I dont think hirachial navigation is the solution to the problem.
I don't know what I have to work with...
I thought about using the visabilties of the pages or using a CarouselPage...
Maybe someone has an idea of how to implement this behaviour...
Thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this if the navigation do not change .

In App.xaml.cs

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new page1());
```

Starts with page 1

Then in page 1 a button clicked

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new page2());
    }
```

and in page2 button

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new page3());
    }
```

Page 3 button

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new page4());
    }
```

And then in page 4

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new page1());
    }
```

If using this you might want to remove the backbutton

Comment: I think this does not work if you are using the same pages. I don't want to create "new" pages...

Comment: await Navigation.PushAsync(new page1()); this means navigating to a existing page .

Comment: so the new keyword doesn't mean it is creating a new instance?

Comment: i am making an example now how it works , one moment

Comment: The example has 4 page's and i hide the backbutton , so you can only navigate to the next page . https://github.com/borisoprit/Pagenavigation

Comment: Unfortunatly your link does not seem to work

Comment: Anyways it worked thanks alot

Comment: Glad that it worked, please mark it as answer if the answer helped you.

Comment: The link is working now if your interested